# choose authentication for git pull

Tags: git, github

I want to add a second form of authentication to a github remote.

Here is the situation :

- I have ssh access to a shared server
- In the server, there is a git repository, with a github remote.
- If I run git pull, it asks for a passphrase that I don't have
- I have read/write access to the remote github repository otherwise

How can I add another form of authentication to this repository (even if a single time), to use my password-based github authentication ?

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2

Comment: @PiranhaGeorge Unless I am missing something, that setup has already been done on the server, albeit not by myself. Therefore I don't have access to the passphrase, and I would like to add another pair of ssh credentials without breaking those of the other developer.

Comment: You can add as many as you like, just don't delete the other developer's authorised public key.

Comment: @PiranhaGeorge for a remote server I know how to do that as well. But I want to do this for the github repository. What would be the equivalent of `ssh-copy-id` for a remote git(hub) repository instead of a remote server ?

Comment: Is it your repo on GitHub?

Comment: https://github.com/settings/ssh

Comment: or setup a deploy key, see  answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of setting up SSH keys on GitHub. User level at https://github.com/settings/ssh or repo level:

View the repository on GitHub, click `Settings` to the right, then `Deploy keys`, and add your public key.

Comment: Right, it was simpler than I thought. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

check any git config regarding that:

```
git config  -l
```

If the the result including something like:

```
user.name=some_username
user.email=some_string@some_host.com
```

Try to reset it or unset it:

```
git config --global unset user.name
```

or

```
git config unset user.name
```

set something:

```
git config --global user.name my_newname
```

or reset this:

```
remote.origin.url=https://username@example.com/xxxx/projects/ndnu/repositories/git/ndnu
```

Comment: `git config  -l` contains the name/email of the other developer. Could it break it's setup ?

Comment: i suggest you clone a new one in another path. then update "remote.origin.url" for it. leave the user.name.

Comment: Please change that url. Opening it is not really safe at work.